# VBA : Can child sub inherit properties from its parent sub

Tags: excel, vba, module

I am creating an Excel macro that populated as template PowerPoint slide deck with some charts from the workbook.

The act of copy and pasting a chart from Excel to PowerPoint takes a lot of lines of code, so I am trying to move this into a subroutine that I call from the main routine, to keep everything modular.  The below illustrates what I am trying to do.

To me, the only arguments that should vary for each call of the `PasteChart` subroutine is the name of the chart I am copying across (eg `Figure1`, `Figure2`, etc) and the placeholder position on the slide (2, 3, etc).  The slide number I want to define before calling the routines as I need to do other things to the slide as well.

To me, the arguments `wb`, `pptApp`, `ppt`, `SlideNumber` should be inherited from the main routine so that I don't have to keep passing them to the `PasteChart` subroutine.  Ie, these 4 arguments are going to be the same for all calls of the `PasteChart` subroutine.

But if I don't pass them as I have below, my macro won't work.

Is there a way to more elegantly structure the below subroutine?  Or in other words, how can I get the `PasteChart` subroutine to inherit the arguments `wb`, `pptApp`, `ppt`, `SlideNumber` from the main routine?

**Parent Subroutine**

```
Sub CreateSlideDeck()

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook()

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open("D:\Template\Template.pptx", untitled:=msoTrue)
    

    SlideNumber = 3

    Call PasteChart("Figure1", 2, wb, pptApp, ppt, SlideNumber)
    Call PasteChart("Figure2", 3, wb, pptApp, ppt, SlideNumber)
    
End Sub
```

**Child Subroutine**

```
Sub PasteChart(ChartName, Position, wb, pptApp, ppt, SlideNumber)

    wb.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(ChartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    
    pptApp.Activate
    ppt.Slides(SlideNumber).Select
    ppt.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.Placeholders(Position).Select
    ppt.Windows(1).view.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer: No.  As to a more elegant solution, perhaps create a class that hold all the relevant details.  And FWIW Call is obsolete and not needed.  Use `PasteChart "Figure1", 2, wb, pptApp, ppt, SlideNumber`

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but you can create them as global variables within the module.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim ppt As Object
Dim SlideNumber As Long

Sub CreateSlideDeck()
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook()

    Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open("D:\Template\Template.pptx", untitled:=msoTrue)
    
    SlideNumber = 3

    Call PasteChart("Figure1", 2)
    Call PasteChart("Figure2", 3)
End Sub

Sub PasteChart(ByVal ChartName As String, ByVal Position As Long)
    wb.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects(ChartName).Activate
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    
    pptApp.Activate
    ppt.Slides(SlideNumber).Select
    ppt.Slides(SlideNumber).Shapes.Placeholders(Position).Select
    ppt.Windows(1).View.Paste
End Sub
```

Would I do that?  Probably not but each to their own and if you have a use case and it works for you then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a configuration array - and then iterate:

```vb
Sub createSlideDeck()

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook()

Set pptApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open("D:\Template\Template.pptx", untitled:=msoTrue)


Dim arr(3, 2)   'array that takes configuration of all charts
'Chartname | Position | Slidenumber
arr(0, 0) = "Figure1": arr(0, 1) = 2: arr(0, 2) = 3
arr(1, 0) = "Figure2": arr(1, 1) = 3: arr(1, 2) = 3
arr(2, 0) = "Figure3": arr(2, 1) = 4: arr(2, 2) = 3

Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(arr, 1)
    PasteChart arr(i, 0), arr(i, 1), wb, pptApp, ppt, arr(i, 2)
Next

End Sub
```